# How to set the default website page through htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, web-hosting, shared-hosting, cpanel

I am currently setting up a website from a client on his hosting account. The website address and for some reason doesn't default to .php files (that is: index.php). If I put index.php and there is no index.html file I receive the following error:

> If you feel you have reached this page in error, please contact the
>   web site owner: someemail@example.com If you are the web site owner,
>   it is possible you have reached this page because: The IP address has
>   changed. There has been a server misconfiguration. The site may have
>   been moved to a different server. If you are the owner of this website
>   and were not expecting to see this page, please contact your hosting
>   provider.

His hosting is a shared hosting on cpanel.

Answer (score 32):

Use the DirectoryIndex directive in your .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem was caused by my web-browser cache, as soon as I have cleared my cache it worked!

Answer (score 3):

You can set your default page as the directory index using .htaccess file in 2 ways.

**First method**

```
DirectoryIndex yourfile.php
```

Above code will set 'yourfile.php' as the directory index. But this will applies to all sub folders as well and may occur '404' error for some related urls.

**Second method**

Use this code to set your handler file for the root directory

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /yourfile.php [L]
```

If you want to set a handler file for the sub folder, use this one

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subfolder/$ /yourfile.php [L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

if that doesn't work you might have to work around it by providing index.html like

```
<html><frameset rows="*"><frame src="index.php"></frameset></html>
```

(ofcourse more elaborate)

Comment: If you already suggest a solution of that sort, frame usage is absolutely useless: just set redirect with corresponding `<meta>` tag.